# Running monero service on WIN10 with custom --data-dir

Tags: monerod, monerod-commands

After few hours of trying, I'm unable to run:

```
monerod --start-service --data-dir x:\mydir\monerodir
```

Prior this, service is installed with `monerod --install-service` and this part goes fine.

Also, I'm tryed to run `monerod` with custom config file:

```
monerod --config-file x:\mydir\bitmonero.conf
```

and this also does not capture any settings from config file in which is:

```
data-dir x:\mydir\monerodir
```

ver is: *'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.3.1-release)*

Please for  help about this, and I will appreciate some proved recipe.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this on Windows using NTSF symlinks:

Open an elevated CMD window. Then:

```
mklink /D "C:\ProgramData\bitmonero" "x:\mydir\monerodir"
```

Then you don't need to specify any other command line options when starting the monero daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Open an elevated command prompt to install as a service and pass your additional parameters at that time

```
monerod --install-service --data-dir x:\mydir\monerodir
```